# How to use regular expressions in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have few files in blob storage which all are named using Regular expressions.
For eg-

File Regular Expression for CSV: `“^(CSV).*csv$”`
and File Name: `CSV_309846814_POA DOLA Alignment.csv`

For file XML: `“^(XML).*xml$”`
File name `XML_ARotaryTable_20231122_214135.specvalues.xml`

How do I filter them in Filter activity so that Just files matching this RegEx will be pickek up by ADF pipeline.
For now I'm using `Or` with `contains` in filter for '`.csv`' and '.`xml`' files to filter.
Since this is taking all files with csv and xml extensions, I need to follow Regular expressions to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Regex expression in ADF. For your requirement, you can use `startswith` and `endswith` functions. Below is the expression:

```
@or(and(startswith(item().name,'CSV'),endswith(item().name,'.csv')),
and(startswith(item().name,'XML'),endswith(item().name,'.xml')))
```

This expression in Azure Data Factory filter activity will select files whose names either starts with "CSV" and ends with ".csv" or starts with "XML" and ends with ".xml".

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to follow for my kind of problem using those expressions ? because I was asked to get a solution for this since the files follows these patterns.

Comment: Regex expression is not possible. You can try above expression. This will give the same output

Comment: Do the above solution support more than two file types, let say I have a '.hr' file and a .log file besides csv and xml?

Comment: If you want to filter the files starting with `CSV or XML` and ends with `.csv or .xml` from the list of names, this expression will filter.

Comment: Did you try the above solution?

Comment: Yes, it works with 2 types of files. With more than two types its showing wrong syntax. So, CSV, XML working. Now I have to add .hr and .log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256148/discussion-between-crime-master-gogo-and-aswin).

Comment: You can give the expression as `@and(startswith(item().name,'FTP_'),or(or(endswith(item().name,'.xml'),endswith(item().name,'.csv')),or(endswith(item().name,'.hr'),endswith(item().name,'.log'))))`